# Requesting pages and reading results with Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, http, actionscript

I have a Flash object hosted on foo.com. When I run it, I want it to send a HTTP request to foo.com, and retrieve the results along with HTTP headers.

How would one achieve this with Flash? (AS 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`URLLoader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLLoader.html) to send a [`URLRequest`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLRequest.html) to foo.com. You can add headers by pushing new `URLRequestHeader's` onto the [`URLRequest.requestHeaders`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLRequest.html#requestHeaders) array. I'm not sure about *reading* the headers though. I think it's possible with [sockets](http://www.blog.lessrain.com/as3-java-socket-connections-to-ports-below-1024/) and AIR seems to have the `httpResponseStatus` event (not `httpStatus` like the Flash API) which

> unlike the httpStatus event, the
>   httpResponseStatus event is delivered
>   before any response data. Also, **the
>   httpResponseStatus event includes
>   values for the responseHeaders and
>   responseURL properties** (which are
>   undefined for an httpStatus event.
>   Note that the httpResponseStatus event
>   (if any) will be sent before (and in
>   addition to) any complete or error
>   event.